# List all files with ID3v2.2 tag in folder

Tags: ffmpeg, metadata, id3v2, id3-tag, eyed3

I have a folder of around 40000 audio files and I need to find all tracks with an ID3v2.2 tag on them and add them to a folder.

I am very new to eyed3 and ffmpeg, so is there a way to use one of these to get the files I need? I've read both docs and found the 'tag-version' function and 'display' pattern for eyed3, but I'm not sure how to use them.

Thanks!

Comment: Are you sure you are looking for ID3 v2.2 tags? Not v2.3 or v2.4?

Comment: 100% sure, ~I found some Serato test tracks that are id3v2.2 and I want to see if any others exist in my collection. I've tried looking for specs on 2.2 but they are sporadic. Any specific info or related would help. Thanks!

Comment: [The docs](https://eyed3.readthedocs.io/en/latest/) imply that you just have to scan the output of _eyeD3_ for a line that equals to `ID3 v2.2:`. Otherwise just look at the first 4 bytes of a file: if it is `"ID3\x02"` then you deal with v2.2. Both options are trivial.